# Choose parameters for Hough transform

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I am trying to extract the rectangles in a scanned image, something like this : [image]

 I'm using OpenCV and following [this tutorial](http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2013/04/tutorial-detecting-multiple-rectangles.html) and I came to this code

```
private static Mat detectLinesHough(Mat img) {
    Mat lines = new Mat();
    // Mat edges = new Mat();
    // Imgproc.Canny(img, edges, 20, 60);
    int threshold = 80;
    int minLineLength = 10;
    int maxLineGap = 5;
    double rho = 0.4;
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(img, lines, rho, Math.PI / 180, threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
    System.out.println(lines.cols());
    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double x1 = vec[0], y1 = vec[1], x2 = vec[2], y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
        Core.line(lines, start, end, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    }
    return img;
}
```

For example, with the parameters like in the code from above I get the following result :
[image]

 The result is not satisfying, so the questions is - how should I choose the parameters to select all the rectangles and not to many letters ?

Answer (score 0):

I have three suggestions to enhance the results:

1. You should make 'minLineLength' as high as possible and 'maxLineGap' as low as possible, so that the lines you search for are still found.
2. Process the lines and check for the angle, as your rectangle lines are either parallel or perpendicular to your x-Axis. You could discard lines that are not in a certain angle range.
3. Look for corners and discard every line that is not connected to a corner.